# Django-allauth TypeError

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I've got the following error, while using Django-allauth:

```
TypeError at /accounts/facebook/login/token/
expected string or buffer


C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\adapter.py in clean_username
        if not USERNAME_REGEX.match(username):
```

I don't use username in my authentication (only email and password).
What should I do?
Maybe it is connected with configuration parameters.

In addition (don't know whether it matters), account to which I connect is in cyrillian.

Comment: Please list your allauth settings. Also, at what stage of the login process do you see this error?

Comment: Issue is resolved. I forgot to turn off username.

Comment: @AndrewFount I have the same issue, can you please explain how did you do it?

Comment: In settings set ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD=None

Comment: @AndrewFount I receive an AssertionError, should I setup the ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD to the name of the field?

Comment: Yes. Try to play with other parameters to solve assertion errors, but ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD should be set to None.